# HTTPD Issue on Mac Sierra OS - Fails to start on a fresh brew installation

Tags: macos, apache, apache2

Trying to install Apache on my MAC, using the homebrew.
When I do: `brew services start httpd`
I get the following error:

```
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/{USERNAME}Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` exited with 133.
```

/usr/local/etc/httpd/.conf file [[HERE]](https://pastebin.com/KVpqH61Y)

/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf [[HERE]](https://pastebin.com/D3vzC0aw)

When I do `sudo brew services start httpd`

```
Error: undefined method `first' for "/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd":String
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/services_cli.rb:316:in `block in start'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/services_cli.rb:290:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/services_cli.rb:290:in `start'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/services_cli.rb:94:in `run!'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/cmd/services.rb:48:in `services'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:122:in `<main>'
```